# getting **QObject::moveToThread:** issue while I am running face detection python script using opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have made one python script for face detection using opencv-python and I am using **Deep Learning-based Face Detector in OpenCV** this method for face detection.

when I try to run the script it works perfectly. except, one thing I am getting this issue in my terminal for each iteration of the loop.

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x557189d700e0) is not the object's thread (0x55718a9b9530).
Cannot move to target thread (0x557189d700e0)

QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x557189d700e0) is not the object's thread (0x55718a9b9530).
Cannot move to target thread (0x557189d700e0)

QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x557189d700e0) is not the object's thread (0x55718a9b9530).
Cannot move to target thread (0x557189d700e0)
```

I am not able to find what is happening in reality. I have used different solutions from StackOverflow but none of them is actually working in my case.

I am using this version of opencv and python.

```
cv2.__version__ --> 4.5.2
Python --> 3.8.3
```

If anyone knows the solution to this issue please acknowledge me. it would be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this way and in my case, it worked.

Solution:

OpenCV downgrade

Pip uninstall opencv-python

Pip install opencv-python==4.1.2.30

[Got solution from this article](https://www.programmersought.com/article/20797211182/)